# Click on button with css selector (python)

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I am currently in the process of writing my first bot in Python, the bot selects all buttons except the last one. this is the button: "

```html
 <button type = "button" onclick = "consent_consent_crossregistration ('consent_crossregistration', true);" class = "dtyrd-button dtyrd-button-color-green btn-circle" data-dismiss = "modal" style = "width: 100%; float: left;" data-parsley-group = "block-2"> Yes </button>
```

The following is my code

```py
button = driver.find_element_by_name('button.dtyrd-button dtyrd-button-color-green btn-circle').click()
```

and the following error message is displayed: `AttributeError`: '`WebDriver`' object has no attribute '`find_element_by_class`'

[This is a Screen of Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ7f0.jpg)

Comment: Could you also provide how you imported the driver and initialize it?

Comment: Yeah, please have a look at screenshot   http://prntscr.com/13o4hnf

Answer (score 0):

the `click()` returns void so there's no need to save anything into a variable.

Instead of this :

```
button = driver.find_element_by_name('button.dtyrd-button dtyrd-button-color-green btn-circle').click()
```

use this :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.dtyrd-button.dtyrd-button-color-green.btn-circle').click()
```

The name locator that you are trying to use contains spaces, you can not use that with `driver.find_element_by_name`, I have removed the spaces and using that as a `css_selector`.